# std::set method to get number of elements lower than a given element?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Does `std::set` support any method that returns the number of elements that are lower than a given element?

I know that we have `lower_bound` that returns the iterator to the lower bound of the given element; but it does not return to me the number of elements before a given element.

I know that I can iterate from the beginning to the lower bound iterator; but this will take `O(n)` time in the worst case. Do we have a method that does this in `O(logn)`?

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically have a `std::set`, then you can use the custom [`std::set::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) like this:

```
auto lb = s.lower_bound(key);
```

which is guaranteed `O(log n)` complexity.

And to get the count of elements, you can use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) like this:

```
auto count = std::distance(s.begin(), s.lower_bound(key));
```

However, `std::set` doesn't support random access iterators, so the `std::distance` call has `O(n)` complexity.

---

If you have some sorted range, you can still use `lower_bound` and `distance` like this:

```
auto lb = std::lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), key);
auto count = std::distance(s.begin(), lb);
```

But note that if `s` doesn't support random access, then *both* these operations have `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that `std::distance(s.begin(), s.lower_bound(key));` has `O(log(n))` complexity.  Certainly the call to `lower_bound` does, but the call to `distance` is `O(n)` (for a potentially smaller `n`)

Comment: @MarshallClow From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) *if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.* Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What you're missing is that a set does not have random-access iterators.

Comment: @MarshallClow That's true, thanks. Edited the answer.